# run event once only

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have code to check for browser and at the moment it is running each time i refresh page. is it possible to run only once on each visit so if i refresh or are taken to that page by link then the code is ignored. thanks

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="8.0" || $.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="7.0") 
            alert("Please upgrade your browser to at least version 8.0 in order to use all the features of this site.\n\nThank you.");
    </script>
```

updated code supplied by darin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date(); date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000)); $.cookie("explorer", "foo",{ expires: date });
        var cookie = $.cookie('explorer');

    if (cookie == null) {
        // the cookie is not present => you may do the checks
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '8.0') {
            // set the cookie so that the next time the user visits this page
            // he doesn't get the alert message
            $.cookie('explorer', 'true');
            alert("Please upgrade your browser to at least version 8.0 in order to use all the features of this site.\n\nThank you.");
        }
    }
 </script>
```

the alert is not firing though

Comment: 1. Use a cookie. 2. Are you really urging IE8 users to upgrade to IE8?

Comment: that is just there as a sample. will be 6/7. thanks

Comment: @bollo I recommend IE conditional comments for IE-targeting. It's better because it doesn't depend on jQuery or JavaScript in general. SCRIPT elements inside conditional comments will run in the specified versions of IE immediately (which is good because you can place that SCRIPT block at the top of the page).

Comment: @sime. that would be very useful if css is being used to target a specific browser. thanks

Comment: @bollo It is also very useful if JavaScript is being used to target IE... (not just CSS)

Comment: @sime. i could only find info that related to css? thanks

Comment: @bollo You can put any HTML elements inside IE conditional comments. If you put a SCRIPT element inside, then the JavaScript code inside that SCRIPT element executed only if the conditional comment evaluates to true. This means that you can execute JS code conditionally...

Comment: @sime. thank you. so it proves useful for targeting that browser with certain JS functions, redirect etc. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to set a cookie remembering what the last version you saw was and only nag the user if you don't see the cookie or if the version changes but still isn't what you want.

---

**Side note**: Your check, as quoted, will nag someone using IE8 that they need to at least use IE8. Seems odd. If you really want browser sniffing, perhaps:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) < 8) {
    // Do whatever you're going to do with them having IE < 8.0
}
```

---

**Off-topic**: This sort of nagging pop-up is out of fashion. Instead, if there are parts of your site that won't work without certain browser features, use *feature detection* (rather than browser sniffing) to check for them and disable only the relevant parts (perhaps with a message, when the user tries to use that part of your site, saying why they can't). You can find a bunch of useful feature tests [here](http://kangax.github.com/cft/) and [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html). See also [`jQuery.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/).

Comment: @bollo: Glad that helped. (I also just flagged up `jQuery.support`, which you might want to look at.)

Comment: @TJ. thanks for the jquery.support link. very useful information. def one for the bookmark

Answer (score 1):

You could use cookies. So you may check for the presence of some custom cookie and if not present show the message and emit the cookie so that the next time the message is not shown. Here's a nice [plugin for jquery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) that simplifies reading and writing cookies:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cookie = $.cookie('some_cookie_name');
    if (cookie == null) {
        // the cookie is not present => you may do the checks
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '7.0') {
            // set the cookie so that the next time the user visits this page
            // he doesn't get the alert message
            $.cookie('some_cookie_name', 'true');
            alert("Please upgrade your browser to at least version 8.0 in order to use all the features of this site.\n\nThank you.");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @darin. do i need to use plugin to use this? because i am getting: $.cookie is not a function in firebug? thanks

Comment: @bollo, yes you need. I've linked to it in my answer: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Comment: @darin. i installed plugin and it fired once but when i closed browser and emptied all TIF and cookie files it didn't fire? is this cookie set forever? thanks

Comment: @bollo, you have the possibility to set an expiration date to make the cookie persistent. This way it will survive browser restarts. For example to define a persistent cookie valid for 30 minutes: `var date = new Date(); date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000)); $.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });`. Of course if the user clears the cookies in his browser it will disappear and he will be asked again but that would be normal.

Comment: @darin. sorry to be slow on the uptake. but i cannot see a cookie being set in explorer? what am i missing here? thanks

Comment: @bollo, are cookies enabled? Have you verified that the line supposed to create the cookie is being executed in your code?

Comment: @darin. it worked once and the alert fired but didn,t work again. before i cleared the TIF there was no cookie being set. yes they are enabled. i shall recheck the code. thanks

Comment: @darin. had to update my original post updated code. too many characters to place in comment. thanks

Comment: @bollo, the alert is not firing probably because the way you are checking your browser version is wrong. Verify this if condition and whether all it's components are satisfied.

Comment: @darin. the if condition looks fine. if i clear TIF then cookie should ==null? cannot see the prob. thanks

Comment: @darin. also the cookie is being set: explorer
foo
localhost/nova/
1088
432307840
30157085
3913464320
30157080
*
BTW, what is the function of 'foo' as in your example. thanks

Comment: thanks for your help guys. i am still struggling with this so i shall re-open a new thread.